# Delete unrecognized html in text

Tags: android, html, notifications

How can delete with android resources unrecognized `html` text/ `CSS` styles and show text without it?

Comment: what are examples of "unrecognized html css"?

Comment: TextView or spanned, then you show it in notification, you use Html.fromHtml and some tags 
are shown as text, not as styles.